# Very slow simple query

Tags: google-bigquery

Running a query such as the following:

```
SELECT some_column FROM [myproject.mytable] LIMIT 1000
```

Over a dataset that is approximately 240 million rows (where the columns queryable size is less than 2GB) takes over 140 seconds to complete.

Is there something I can do to improve the tables query performance? Or am I missing something?

Edit:

Job id for reference: job__aamhffrd45gp6VEYDjQCK1JDH8

Edit 2:

Ive identified a pattern which is that it seems to be only the table that is currently being written to that is exceedingly slow, however this is still a large problem for me.

Comment: This is not normal, but a BQ engineer could verify. For that king of support, you will need to provide a job id. Also: It might be a network problem (transmitting 1000 results). Can you try the same query with LIMIT 10?

Comment: The limit did not seem to effect it at all (and I am trying from the Web ui currently) - I will post a job ID soon.

Comment: @EwanWalker try this
`SELECT some_column FROM [myproject.mytable] a JOIN (SELECT id FROM [myproject.mytable] ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000, 10) as b ON b.id = a.id`

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov Unfortunately as this is a raw statistical table there are no IDs as there is no value to having one in such a data set (as far as I know being that it is non-relational data)

Comment: @AlexanderGrebenshikov he is using Google Bigquery and not MySQL.

Comment: Hey Ewan! I also saw similar long responses yesterday, but that went away since then. Can you confirm if you still see this kind of increased latency now?

Comment: @Patrice it seems to have been getting better as of last night.

Comment: @EwanWalker then it's likely this was just a hiccup of the system and it auto-recovered? I think I saw it super slow on October 25th, and it got better around late-ish evening

Comment: @Patrice its actually been up and down for me, I've been getting these spikes repeatedly for some time now - unfortunately.

Comment: @EwanWalker Well I know that there's been some up and downs lately on BQ's speed (as of October 20th or so), but if this pre-dates that, I would suggest filing an issue here https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list :)

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of posting this, I have been informed that Google knows of the issue and there is no ETA on a fix for the issue as of yet. This ended up being an issue on their end.